# Polynomial curve fit - where "y" is not zero

Tags: polynomials

I have an equation to fit a curve of phosphorus concentration

$$\text{Response} \\ = 1.927596\cdot10^{-03} + 4.631966\cdot10^{-04} \cdot\text{concentration} + 3.297547\cdot10^{-08}\cdot\text{concentration}^2$$

I usually use it to predict my absorbance by an know concentration solution.

For example, using the concentration 11,473:

$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ ;   then , $f(x) =  1,927596E-03 + 4,631966E-04*11.473 + 3,297547E-08*11,473^2$ that is 0,0072.

But now, I want to use the absorbance to predict the concentration, doing the reverse path.  Is it possible??  I'm a biologist, know little bit about math and I can't solve that problem .

Can you help me?

Comment: Look up the quadratic formula $x=\frac{-b\plusminus\sqrt(b^2-4ac)}{2a}

Comment: I suspect this might get a better answer at stats.stackexchange.com . ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Paul : That may be something to be done, be recall that when you fit a straight line $y=a +bx$ to predict $y$ based on $x$, you don't use the inverse function of that to predict $x$ based on $y$, especially if the correlation is fairly low. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Paul : Note also $p\pm q$ can be coded in MathJax as p\pm q. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Done in a rush & I thought I deleted the comment. Probably correct about quadratic root as a good estimator.